# Primary Category not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress theme. The sticky article is posted at the top with a featured image, and the breadcrumbs beneath are displaying in alphabetical order no matter what.. There are 3 bread crumbs. I need the 1st breadcrumb as it is now to be in the 2nd position, 2nd goes to 3rd, and 3rd goes to first. I've tried changing the primary category, but EVERY time I do the website crashes with a 503 error. Does anybody know what's going on? Thanks!

Comment: Visual reference and code would be very useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to install another free plugin that arranged them the correct way. It seemed impossible to do in the code.